# How do you keep a list looping, whilst removing a number the user inputs each time? (Python + Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Made a list where I want the user to insert `x` followed by a number. once they have inputted, say `x1`, I would like `x1` to be removed from the list as they are asked to input another number starting with `x`.

I want the list to be on loop as well, only stopping until one of the groups (of three number) has been chosen.

Disclaimer - I am a beginner at Python + Jupyter Notebook

```
allwins = (('x1','x2','x3'),
         ('x4','x5','x6'),
         ('x7','x8','x9'),
         ('x1','x4','x7'),
         ('x2','x5','x8'),
         ('x3','x6','x9'),
         ('x1','x5','x9'),
         ('x7','x5','x3'))
in_item = input("Please enter x followed by a number 1-9: ")
if in_item in allsolutions:
    input("Good choice. Now pick another number starting with x: ")
else in_item not in allsolutions:
    input("That did not work. Try again: ")
```

Idk how to keep loop for atleast a few times until the user inputs 3 diff numbers that makes a group.

Comment: What is `allsolutions`? The variable is named `allwins`. Also, it's not a list, it's a tuple of tuples. You can't modify tuples.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove something from a tuple, so you need to make the inner tuples lists.

Then you need to loop over the main tuple, removing the input from each of them if it exists. After you do this you can check if the list is empty.

```
allwins = (
    ['x1','x2','x3'],
    ['x4','x5','x6'],
    ['x7','x8','x9'],
    ['x1','x4','x7'],
    ['x2','x5','x8'],
    ['x3','x6','x9'],
    ['x1','x5','x9'],
    ['x7','x5','x3'])

while True:
    in_item = input("Please enter x followed by a number 1-9: ")
    item_found = False
    solution_found = False
    for sublist in allwins:
        if in_item in sublist:
            sublist.remove(in_item)
            item_found = True
            if sublist == []:
                solution_found = True
    if solution_found:
        print("You found all of them, congratulations!")
        break
    elif item_found:
        print("Good choice, now pick another")
    else:
        print("That did not work, now try again")
```